# Having trouble understanding htaccess/mod_rewrite, apache isn't rewriting url as intended

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect any request to my laravel project's index.php, located at localhost/test1/public/. here is my htaccess in the root folder:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /test1/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^()$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

To my understanding, anything after localhost/ will be put into the url variables. so for example. localhost/nothing should be rewritten to localhost/test1/public/index.php?url=nothing ... right?

when i directly type localhost/test1/public/index.php?url=nothing the page loads properly, but typing localhost/nothing currently gives me a 404 error. Is there any way i can check what URLs are being rewritten to?

Another assumption of mine that I'm not sure about is the .htaccess located in /test1/public will rewrite the url that was rewritten by the .htaccess file in root. is that correct? here is the  laravel project's htaccess located in /test1/public.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You ask: "Is there any way i can check what URLs are being rewritten to?". Yes, there is. Take a look at the documentation. You are looking for "rewrite logging". It allows you to observe each and every step the request engine walks through, including the patterns it applies and decisions it takes.

Comment: Your second question is: "is that correct?". Yes, that is correct.

Comment: The root issue here _probably_ is that your configuration file in the hosts root folder does not get considered. You can easily test that by placing a definite syntax error in that file. If it is considered at all (parsed and evaluated), then you will receive a corresponding entry in the http server's error log file (which you have to monitor anyway). If not you have your answer, in that case take a look at the documentation of the `AllowOverride` directive.

Comment: Oh, and just a hint: you want to _internally rewrite_ incoming requests. You do _not_ actually want to _externally redirect_ them. Just saying, might help with your research.

Comment: thanks for the tips, appreciate it. i am getting entries in the error log file, and it shows me that its being written as intended. " rewrite 'nothing' -> 'test1/public/index.php?url=nothing' " 
the last line even says "pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/test1/public/index.php"

one thing is that the log lines for the .htaccess located in /public/ dont mention any args. so im guessing it drops them, which makes things even more confusing